# Deserialize Json Property's Property to Property

Tags: c#, json.net

In json.net, how can I deserialize this json:

```
{
    "items": {
        "count": 1,
        "data": [
             { 
                 ...
             },
             ...
        ],
    }
}
```

To this C# class:

```
class MyData
{
    [JsonProperty("items/data")] // this doesn't work
    public List<object> Items { get; set; }
}
```

-

```
// Then this doesn't populate Items
MyData data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyData>(json);
```

Is there an elegant way of doing this with json.net?

Comment: Json.NET requires a corresponding POCO for each JSON object/"level" to get a strongly typed de-serialization .. *or* the use of a [Custom JsonConverter](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just thought of how I could do this:

```
var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
jObject["items"] = jObject["items"]["data"];

MyData data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyData>(jObject.ToString());
```

Anyone have a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

For populate items you should have this

```
public class Datum
{
}

public class Items
{
    public int count { get; set; }
    public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Items items { get; set; }
}
```

and then use this:

```
MyData data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

Comment: Yes I could do that, but the `Count` information is useless. I don't want it. I have no control over the json.